# erro ao instalar mongoose em win server 2008 r2

Tags: node.js, mongoose

O erro abaixo é apresentado ao instalar o mongoose no sistema op. server 2008r2

Todos os aplicativos estao instalados de forma correta. mas o banco parece nao compilar.

```
c:\program files\iisnode\www\pmt\node_modules\bson\node_modules\bson-ext\node_m odules\nan\nan_new.h(208): warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'int64_t ' to 'double', possible loss of data [C:\Program Files\iisnode\www\pmt\node_mod ules\bson\node_modules\bson-ext\build\bson.vcxproj] ..\ext\bson.cc(589) : see reference to function template instantiatio n 'v8::Local NanNew(A0)' being compiled with [ A0=int64_t ]

C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\shared\ws2ipdef.h(124): warning C4005: 'IP_MULTICAST_LOOP' : macro redefinition (..\lib\win32\wrappers\securit y_credentials.cc) [C:\Program Files\iisnode\www\pmt\node_modules\mongoose\node_ modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winsock.h(340) : s ee previous definition of 'IP_MULTICAST_LOOP' C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\shared\ws2ipdef.h(125): warning C4005: 'IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP' : macro redefinition (..\lib\win32\wrappers\securit y_credentials.cc) [C:\Program Files\iisnode\www\pmt\node_modules\mongoose\node_ modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winsock.h(341) : s ee previous definition of 'IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP' C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\shared\ws2ipdef.h(126): warning C4005: 'IP_DROP_MEMBERSHIP' : macro redefinition (..\lib\win32\wrappers\securi ty_credentials.cc) [C:\Program Files\iisnode\www\pmt\node_modules\mongoose\node _modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winsock.h(342) : s ee previous definition of 'IP_DROP_MEMBERSHIP' C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\shared\ws2ipdef.h(127): warning C4005: 'IP_DONTFRAGMENT' : macro redefinition (..\lib\win32\wrappers\security_ credentials.cc) [C:\Program Files\iisnode\www\pmt\node_modules\mongoose\node_mo dules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winsock.h(345) : s ee previous definition of 'IP_DONTFRAGMENT' C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\shared\ws2ipdef.h(202): error C 2079: '_SOCKADDR_INET::Ipv4' uses undefined struct 'sockaddr_in' (..\lib\win32\ wrappers\security_credentials.cc) [C:\Program Files\iisnode\www\pmt\node_module s\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\shared\ws2ipdef.h(715): error C 2011: 'ip_mreq' : 'struct' type redefinition (..\lib\win32\wrappers\security_cr edentials.cc) [C:\Program Files\iisnode\www\pmt\node_modules\mongoose\node_modu les\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winsock.h(355) : s ee declaration of 'ip_mreq' C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\ws2tcpip.h(729): error C3861 : 'WSASetLastError': identifier not found (..\lib\win32\wrappers\security_crede ntials.cc) [C:\Program Files\iisnode\www\pmt\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules \mongodb\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\ws2tcpip.h(736): error C3861 : 'WSASetLastError': identifier not found (..\lib\win32\wrappers\security_crede ntials.cc) [C:\Program Files\iisnode\www\pmt\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules \mongodb\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\ws2tcpip.h(775): error C3861 : 'WSASetLastError': identifier not found (..\lib\win32\wrappers\security_crede ntials.cc) [C:\Program Files\iisnode\www\pmt\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules \mongodb\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\ws2tcpip.h(782): error C3861 : 'WSASetLastError': identifier not found (..\lib\win32\wrappers\security_crede ntials.cc) [C:\Program Files\iisnode\www\pmt\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules \mongodb\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\ws2tcpip.h(826): error C3861 : 'WSASetLastError': identifier not found (..\lib\win32\wrappers\security_crede ntials.cc) [C:\Program Files\iisnode\www\pmt\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules \mongodb\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\ws2tcpip.h(833): error C3861 : 'WSASetLastError': identifier not found (..\lib\win32\wrappers\security_crede ntials.cc) [C:\Program Files\iisnode\www\pmt\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules \mongodb\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\ws2tcpip.h(874): error C3861 : 'WSASetLastError': identifier not found (..\lib\win32\wrappers\security_crede ntials.cc) [C:\Program Files\iisnode\www\pmt\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules \mongodb\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\ws2tcpip.h(881): error C3861 : 'WSASetLastError': identifier not found (..\lib\win32\wrappers\security_crede ntials.cc) [C:\Program Files\iisnode\www\pmt\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules \mongodb\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj] C:\Users\andrei.graca.node-gyp\0.12.4\deps\uv\include\uv.h(974): error C2079: 'uv_interface_address_s::address4' uses undefined struct 'sockaddr_in' (..\lib\ win32\wrappers\security_credentials.cc) [C:\Program Files\iisnode\www\pmt\node_ modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxp roj] C:\Users\andrei.graca.node-gyp\0.12.4\deps\uv\include\uv.h(978): error C2079: 'uv_interface_address_s::netmask4' uses undefined struct 'sockaddr_in' (..\lib\ win32\wrappers\security_credentials.cc) [C:\Program Files\iisnode\www\pmt\node_ modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxp roj] c:\program files\iisnode\www\pmt\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\nod e_modules\kerberos\lib\win32\wrappers\security_credentials.h(52): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (. .\lib\win32\wrappers\security_credentials.cc) [C:\Program Files\iisnode\www\pmt \node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerbero s.vcxproj] c:\program files\iisnode\www\pmt\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\nod e_modules\kerberos\lib\win32\wrappers\security_credentials.h(52): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '&' (..\lib\win32\wrappers\security_credentia ls.cc) [C:\Program Files\iisnode\www\pmt\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mon godb\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj] c:\program files\iisnode\www\pmt\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\nod e_modules\kerberos\lib\win32\wrappers\security_credentials.h(53): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (. .\lib\win32\wrappers\security_credentials.cc) [C:\Program Files\iisnode\www\pmt \node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerbero s.vcxproj] c:\program files\iisnode\www\pmt\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\nod e_modules\kerberos\lib\win32\wrappers\security_credentials.h(53): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '&' (..\lib\win32\wrappers\security_credentia ls.cc) [C:\Program Files\iisnode\www\pmt\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mon godb\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj] c:\program files\iisnode\www\pmt\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\nod e_modules\kerberos\lib\win32\wrappers\security_credentials.h(60): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (. .\lib\win32\wrappers\security_credentials.cc) [C:\Program Files\iisnode\www\pmt \node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerbero s.vcxproj] c:\program files\iisnode\www\pmt\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\nod e_modules\kerberos\lib\win32\wrappers\security_credentials.h(60): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '&' (..\lib\win32\wrappers\security_credentia ls.cc) [C:\Program Files\iisnode\www\pmt\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mon godb\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj] c:\program files\iisnode\www\pmt\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\nod e_modules\kerberos\lib\win32\wrappers\security_credentials.h(47): error C2819: type 'v8::Persistent>' does not have an overloaded member 'operator ->' [C:\Program Files\iisnode\www\ pmt\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerb eros.vcxproj] with [ T=v8::FunctionTemplate ] (..\lib\win32\wrappers\security_credentials.cc) did you intend to use '.' instead? c:\program files\iisnode\www\pmt\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\nod e_modules\kerberos\lib\win32\wrappers\security_credentials.h(47): error C2039: 'HasInstance' : is not a member of 'v8::Persistent>' [C:\Program Files\iisnode\www\pmt\node_modules\mo ngoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj] with [ T=v8::FunctionTemplate ] (..\lib\win32\wrappers\security_credentials.cc) ..\lib\win32\wrappers\security_credentials.cc(22): error C2248: 'v8::HandleScop e::HandleScope' : cannot access protected member declared in class 'v8::HandleS cope' [C:\Program Files\iisnode\www\pmt\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mong odb\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj] C:\Users\andrei.graca.node-gyp\0.12.4\deps\v8\include\v8.h(816) : se e declaration of 'v8::HandleScope::HandleScope' C:\Users\andrei.graca.node-gyp\0.12.4\deps\v8\include\v8.h(800) : se e declaration of 'v8::HandleScope' ..\lib\win32\wrappers\security_credentials.cc(23): error C2039: 'New' : is not a member of 'v8::String' [C:\Program Files\iisnode\www\pmt\node_modules\mongoos e\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj] C:\Users\andrei.graca.node-gyp\0.12.4\deps\v8\include\v8.h(1599) : s ee declaration of 'v8::String' ..\lib\win32\wrappers\security_credentials.cc(23): error C3861: 'ThrowException ': identifier not found [C:\Program Files\iisnode\www\pmt\node_modules\mongoose \node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj] ..\lib\win32\wrappers\security_credentials.cc(23): error C3861: 'New': identifi er not found [C:\Program Files\iisnode\www\pmt\node_modules\mongoose\node_modul es\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj] ..\lib\win32\wrappers\security_credentials.cc(27): error C2248: 'v8::HandleScop e::HandleScope' : cannot access protected member declared in class 'v8::HandleS cope' [C:\Program Files\iisnode\www\pmt\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mong odb\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj] C:\Users\andrei.graca.node-gyp\0.12.4\deps\v8\include\v8.h(816) : se e declaration of 'v8::HandleScope::HandleScope' C:\Users\andrei.graca.node-gyp\0.12.4\deps\v8\include\v8.h(800) : se e declaration of 'v8::HandleScope' ..\lib\win32\wrappers\security_credentials.cc(29): error C2039: 'New' : is not a member of 'v8::String' [C:\Program Files\iisnode\www\pmt\node_modules\mongoos e\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj] C:\Users\andrei.graca.node-gyp\0.12.4\deps\v8\include\v8.h(1599) : s ee declaration of 'v8::String' ..\lib\win32\wrappers\security_credentials.cc(29): error C3861: 'New': identifi er not found [C:\Program Files\iisnode\www\pmt\node_modules\mongoose\node_modul es\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj] ..\lib\win32\wrappers\security_credentials.cc(31): error C2660: 'v8::Integer::N ew' : function does not take 1 arguments [C:\Program Files\iisnode\www\pmt\node _modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcx proj] ..\lib\win32\wrappers\security_credentials.cc(31): error C3861: 'NODE_PSYMBOL': identifier not found [C:\Program Files\iisnode\www\pmt\node_modules\mongoose\n ode_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj] ..\lib\win32\wrappers\security_credentials.cc(32): error C3861: 'ThrowException ': identifier not found [C:\Program Files\iisnode\www\pmt\node_modules\mongoose \node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj] ..\lib\win32\wrappers\security_credentials.cc(43): error C4430: missing type sp ecifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int [C:\Program Files \iisnode\www\pmt\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerber os\build\kerberos.vcxproj] ..\lib\win32\wrappers\security_credentials.cc(43): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '&' [C:\Program Files\iisnode\www\pmt\node_modules\mongoose\ node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj] ..\lib\win32\wrappers\security_credentials.cc(44): error C2248: 'v8::HandleScop e::HandleScope' : cannot access protected member declared in class 'v8::HandleS cope' [C:\Program Files\iisnode\www\pmt\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mong odb\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj] C:\Users\andrei.graca.node-gyp\0.12.4\deps\v8\include\v8.h(816) : se e declaration of 'v8::HandleScope::HandleScope' C:\Users\andrei.graca.node-gyp\0.12.4\deps\v8\include\v8.h(800) : se e declaration of 'v8::HandleScope' ..\lib\win32\wrappers\security_credentials.cc(49): error C2065: 'args' : undecl ared identifier [C:\Program Files\iisnode\www\pmt\node_modules\mongoose\node_mo dules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj] ..\lib\win32\wrappers\security_credentials.cc(49): error C2228: left of '.This' must have class/struct/union [C:\Program Files\iisnode\www\pmt\node_modules\mo ngoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj] type is 'unknown-type' ..\lib\win32\wrappers\security_credentials.cc(51): error C2065: 'args' : undecl ared identifier [C:\Program Files\iisnode\www\pmt\node_modules\mongoose\node_mo dules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj] ..\lib\win32\wrappers\security_credentials.cc(51): error C2228: left of '.This' must have class/struct/union [C:\Program Files\iisnode\www\pmt\node_modules\mo ngoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj] type is 'unknown-type' ..\lib\win32\wrappers\security_credentials.cc(54): error C4430: missing type sp ecifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int [C:\Program Files \iisnode\www\pmt\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerber os\build\kerberos.vcxproj] ..\lib\win32\wrappers\security_credentials.cc(54): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '&' [C:\Program Files\iisnode\www\pmt\node_modules\mongoose\ node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj] ..\lib\win32\wrappers\security_credentials.cc(55): error C2248: 'v8::HandleScop e::HandleScope' : cannot access protected member declared in class 'v8::HandleS cope' [C:\Program Files\iisnode\www\pmt\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mong odb\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj] C:\Users\andrei.graca.node-gyp\0.12.4\deps\v8\include\v8.h(816) : se e declaration of 'v8::HandleScope::HandleScope' C:\Users\andrei.graca.node-gyp\0.12.4\deps\v8\include\v8.h(800) : se e declaration of 'v8::HandleScope' ..\lib\win32\wrappers\security_credentials.cc(61): error C2065: 'args' : undecl ared identifier [C:\Program Files\iisnode\www\pmt\node_modules\mongoose\node_mo dules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj] ..\lib\win32\wrappers\security_credentials.cc(61): error C2228: left of '.Lengt h' must have class/struct/union [C:\Program Files\iisnode\www\pmt\node_modules\ mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj] type is 'unknown-type' ..\lib\win32\wrappers\security_credentials.cc(64): error C2065: 'args' : undecl ared identifier [C:\Program Files\iisnode\www\pmt\node_modules\mongoose\node_mo dules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj] ..\lib\win32\wrappers\security_credentials.cc(64): fatal error C1003: error cou nt exceeds 100; stopping compilation [C:\Program Files\iisnode\www\pmt\node_mod ules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj ]

bson-ext@0.1.7 install C:\Program Files\iisnode\www\pmt\node_modules\bson\node _modules\bson-ext (node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build) || (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror. log) || (exit 0)
```

Comment: Não podes estar à espera que vamos ler essas linhas todas à procura do problema... tens alguma ideia do que pode ser?

Comment: Se eu tivesse ideia do motivo do erro, não estaria publicando minha dúvida!